# PHP file upload on ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload

I have my files uploaded on Ubuntu server. Everything is working except file upload.

I have given the permission to all the files as `0644` and for the folders `0755`.

As per the references i am supposed to change the folder permission to `0777` which i don't want to do.

Is there any other way to enable file upload on ubuntu server without changing the permission from `0755` to `0777` ?

Comment: _"As per the references i am supposed to change the folder permission to 0777 which i don't want to do."_ this is a misconception, and you are right to not doing it, 777 should never be used except to perhaps test that X issue is indeed not a permission issue. However, 755 should, in most cases be good enough as long as your web / apache user is the owner of the folders you are trying to upload to, otherwise you might need to look into group permissions.

Comment: Ok so how do i look into group permissions? Please post if u have any reference

Comment: I'm not gonna do your research, google is your friend and he is willing to help you,.

Comment: Which web server are you using. It is an important detail here.

Comment: I am using Digital Ocean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply 777 permission to any of your files/folders in the server.

The files are not uploading mainly because of two reasons.

1. Incorrect ownership (user:group)
2. Incorrect upload path

[This article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership) will help to setup the proper file/folder ownership.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I checked the path its correct. And the article didnt help me.

Comment: Maybe this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership  But try to Google regarding folder ownership and permission. Hundreds of solutions are available for this.

Comment: Most of the solutions have said to change the permission to 0777